# React While loop architecture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Im trying to create a listener for voice using react-speech-recognition. I have it listening and getting the phrase isolated. It comes with some command startListening, stopListening, finalTranscript, interimTranscript, and resetTranscript. I have it working where I can click a button and it listens, click another button and it stops, click reset and it resets. interimTranscript is basically its first guess at the word, and then after a split second once its sure it turns into finalTranscript. Herein lies my problem. The basic flow is that theres a range slider with two values, when moved it sets off the onChange handler which calls this.startListening().

```
  handleChange(event) {
    console.log(`eventname: ${event.target.name}`)
    console.log(`eventvalue: ${event.target.value}`)
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
    this.props.startListening();
    this.setState({ listening: "Yes"})
  }
```

then in my render I have this if statement which detects the moment the phrase goes from interimTranscript to finalTranscript

```
  render(){
    if(this.props.finalTranscript){
      this.sendCommand();
    }
```

which triggers sendCommand(), Here is one of the issues, finalTranscript will keep adding all the different final transcripts into one long string. So I can say "hello" send command prints "hello" then i say "bye" and send command prints "hello bye", BUT sendcommand() is fired once for each word. so I will hit sendCommand() twice. I got around this by clearing out finalTranscript with resetTranscript

```
  sendCommand(){
    console.log("send command", this.props.finalTranscript);
    this.props.resetTranscript;
  }
```

but then I get this error telling me I shouldn't use this.props.resetTranscript through the render function. I tried creating a while loop in my handle change but kept getting stuck in infinite loops.  What would be a good way to go about creating a while loop to start the voice listener, trigger a post upon final transcript, clear out finalTranscript with resetTranscript, and go back to listening?

```
Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error stated, render methods should be just pure functions. It's meant to return a view that was derived from your state and props, not induce state changes. Not to mention that might cause an infinite render if you're not careful. If you want to do those effects, such as if `this.props.finalTranscript` is truthy (or not empty) send a command. Do that in the lifecycle methods like so.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
 if(this.props.finalTranscript){
  this.sendCommand()
 }
}
```

I assume you're using class components. if you want to use hooks, look into using `useEffect`